# PS3 YLOD question

Tags: ps3, hardware

Im aware there is a lot of YLOD (Yellow light of death) questions and I have read a good few of them, but i couldn't find what i was looking for.
So, I bought a PS3 getting YLOD errors. I have tried reflowing with no success, I would reball the GPU, but it looks like a lot more effort than I would like to put in. I was wondering, if i bought a new GPU (same product code of course), how likely is it that it would fix the issue?

Comment: Goodness I hope you didn't pay a lot for a defective PS3...

Comment: I didn't. I got it cheap enough. I enjoy having a project.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it would fix it, however not very likely.

The YLOD error basically means that the GPU's connection to the Mainboard was interrupted.

The most likely cause for that is overheating, which can damage the contacts to a point where they simply stop working. This means the error might easily be on the mainboard, not the GPU. This can either be temporal, meaning it will fix itself after some time (usually a few days) yet could easily also be permanent.

Overall, Playstations affected by the YLOD tend to be considered unrecoverable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! is there any way to test either part easily? because i enjoy messing around with hardware and would like to have a try anyways.

Comment: @morgi you could always just have a look - sometimes you literally see what's broken on first sight. I don't think there is any way to test it without proper tools, however I am no expert in that area.